# Validation Logic In Model

Tags: php

I was debating putting validation logic in my models (setter functions).  Is this something I should be using a separate object for? Below is something I had in mind.

```
class Person {
     private $name, $setErrors = [];

     public function setName($name){
          if(strlen($name) > 0){
              $this->name = $name;
               return true;
          }
          $this->setErrors[] = "Name must be at least one character";
          return false;
     }
     public function getErrors(){
          return $this->setErrors;
     }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->setName("Bob");
if (count($person->getErrors()) > 0){
     /* Return Errors To View */
}
```

Comment: I put mine under domain object☺

Answer (score 0):

Separating concerns is best practice.

Each class should have a single responsibility.

Also, if you moved the validation logic into a separate class, it can be re-used on multiple fields, not to mention being much easier to unit test.

```
class NameValidator
{
    public function isValid($string) {
         // Logic
    }
}
```